# How to send form-data as a JSON Object..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have some text input and images on my server-side. and
I need to send this data as a JSON object. But I can not send images like this because of FormData.So I need to convert my form data to one single JSON object.
Please Help me...
Thank You..!

HTML part -

```
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtcustomerImage"> <i class="tags icon"></i> Image Of Your NIC</label>
            <input class="form-control-file" id="txtcustomerImage" type="file" name="txtcustomerImage">
            </div>
    </form>
```

Ajax Part -

```
$('#btnCreateNewAccount').click(function () {


    var fileObject = $("#txtcustomerImage")[0].files[0];//access file object from input field
    var fileName = $("#txtcustomerImage")[0].files[0].name; //get file name
    var form = new FormData(); //setup form data object to send file data
    form.append("custImage", fileObject, fileName); //append data



    console.log('clicked..');
    let customerNIC = $('txtcustomerNIC').val();
    let customerName = $('txtcustomerName').val();
    let customerAddress = $('txtcustomerAddress').val();

    console.log(form)

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Sprinf_Final-Back-end/customer",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            customerNIC: customerNIC,
            customerName: customerName,
            customerAddress: customerAddress,

        }),
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.massage == 'Success') {
                alert('Your Account is Successfully Created!When You Log to Server Use Your User Name & Password..!');
                console.log(res);
            } else {
                console.log('error');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Nitpick: This is a [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). It's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to create a `FormData` object if you want to send the data as JSON. You can read the file content with `fileObject.text()` and send it:

```js
$('#btnCreateNewAccount').click(async function() {
  const fileObject = $("#txtcustomerImage")[0].files[0]; //access file object from input field
  const fileName = fileObject.name; //get file name
  const data = JSON.stringify({
      fileObject: await fileObject.text(),
      fileName
  })
  console.log(data);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtcustomerImage"> <i class="tags icon"></i> Image Of Your NIC</label>
    <input class="form-control-file" id="txtcustomerImage" type="file" name="txtcustomerImage">
  </div>
</form>
<button id="btnCreateNewAccount">
Click
</button>
```

Comment: can I save const data in mn SQL DB..?

Comment: @Gathsara The data is const in the client code. After it's sent to the server there is no difference. There is no const in JSON.

Comment: private byte [] custImage - this can store image data..?

Comment: @Gathsara Yes, a byte array can store image data.

Comment: CustomerDTO(custID=null, custName=null, custAddress=null, custImage=null) -- But My value is null..I don't understatad

Comment: jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/Sprinf_Final-Back-end/customer 500
send @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ script.js:21
async function (async)
(anonymous) @ script.js:10
dispatch @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2

Comment: also, I have this message on my client-side.?

Comment: @Gathsara This question is about sending a file in a JSON request. If the backend can't handle it or it expects the request in a specific format it's unrelated to this question. Have you verified that the data is sent? You can open your browser's dev tools, go to the Network tab and analyze the request.

Comment: Where does text() method come from for files?

Comment: Using FormData and multi-part content type is the correct way to do this. Answer is all backwards

Comment: @charlietfl The question explicitly states that the backend only accepts JSON and the file has to be send in a JSON request. So the correct answer is to send multi-part content even though the server doesn't accept it? [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) inherits from [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and `text()` comes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text.